# How to set hard drive spindown while plugged into AC power on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, hard-drive, power-management

I have created a personal file server running Ubuntu server. My only problem is figuring out how to have its hard drive spin down after x minutes. I managed to read the 20hdparm file and it states it will only spin down the hard drive if it detects it's running on battery power. Any ideas?

Comment: In my desktop, it powers down when I'm not using it by default. Have you let it idle for some time and checked?

Comment: After setting the standby time it seems to have turned off as its supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standby timer setting ( -S ).  It does not know or care about batteries.